# Process spawned from service hangs calling Print methods

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, service

I have a service which spawns child processes which in turn write print jobs to the windows spooler.

This works without issue in most places except on one server (running Server 2008 SP2, other 2008 SP2 servers work fine) where the child process hangs when calling:

```
PrintDialog.PrintDocument
```

or if I do the follow it freezes on Write.

```
Dim printWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printDlg.PrintQueue)
printWriter.Write(paginator, printDlg.PrintTicket)
```

or when using

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.Print
```

with no job written to the spooler queue.

However if I kill this process and relaunch the child process manually from command prompt it prints fine.

The main service process in set to logon using the same user account and the process spawned also runs under the same user account so the problem appears to be due to how the process is being started.

I have tried the following when launching the child process:

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo
psi.FileName = exe
psi.Arguments = "ID=" & Id.ToString
psi.UseShellExecute = False
psi.CreateNoWindow = True
psi.Verb = "runas"
psi.RedirectStandardError = True
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
psi.LoadUserProfile = True     
ChildProcess = Process.Start(psi)
```

Is there anything else I can do to get the process launched by the service to act in the same way as if it were launched from cmd prompt?

Answer (score 0):

In general it's not possible to print from a service, I expect you mean a windows service. The reason is that a windows service does not have a desktop (GDI) and therefore doesn't have a printer.

So trying to print from a service is something completly different than printing from a console you opend as a user with a desktop which have a running GDI engine.

There're some hackish workarounds around to print from a service, but that's a pain in the ass and not recommended by Microsoft!

Comment: We have been printing from services for many years. Its only recently we have gone from printing in the service to a process spawned by a service and this works on other servers. As long as the user account has access to the printer its not a problem normally. There is a 64 bit issue in Windows 8 or later but this can be fixed in the registry.

Comment: I should also make it clear that this works on other Server 2008 machines

Comment: @apc I know that it's possible, but it's not supportet from MS so it's not advisable to do so. So when you have this issue only on one 2008 SP2 server what differs between this server and the working ones? I do not belive you can do something in your code. I belive I could be a rights issue or some crazy damged user profiles.

Comment: No differences we've been able to find. My current thinking is its something to do with the session the process is running under but its not something im familiar with.

Comment: @apc Yes this is possible. You should check if the service on both machines uses the same user settings for example.